# My Shiny app works well on local host but is not working when deploying on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, shinyapps

My app works well on the local host but it doesn't work when deploying on shinyapps.io. No any`setwd()`is used in the code of app.
This is the error I get when running the deployed app URL:

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start.

exit status 1
```

These are the packages used in app:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(shinydashboard)
library(fresh)
library(psych)
library(DT)
library(vroom)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggExtra)
library(colourpicker)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(slickR)
library(png)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

I think the problem is that Gene-expression-data-GDSC.csv, which is a very important input file, doesn't upload to the /srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev as it is stated in the logs. Can the problem be because of large size of the file (167 MB)? How can I fix that?
These are the logs:

```
2022-12-06T14:26:10.041546+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Attaching package: ‘ggplot2’
2022-12-06T14:26:10.041809+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:psych’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.041841+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     %+%, alpha
2022-12-06T14:26:10.061608+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Attaching package: ‘ggExtra’
2022-12-06T14:26:10.061844+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.061864+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     runExample
2022-12-06T14:26:10.069203+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Attaching package: ‘colourpicker’
2022-12-06T14:26:10.069470+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following object is masked from ‘package:ggExtra’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.069492+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     runExample
2022-12-06T14:26:10.069738+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.069763+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     runExample
2022-12-06T14:26:10.145997+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Attaching package: ‘shinyWidgets’
2022-12-06T14:26:10.146208+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following object is masked from ‘package:psych’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.146232+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     progressBar
2022-12-06T14:26:10.146469+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following object is masked from ‘package:bs4Dash’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.146495+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     progressBar
2022-12-06T14:26:10.153132+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’
2022-12-06T14:26:10.153379+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shinyWidgets’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.153405+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     alert
2022-12-06T14:26:10.153680+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:colourpicker’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.153708+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     colourInput, colourPicker, runExample, updateColourInput
2022-12-06T14:26:10.153947+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following object is masked from ‘package:ggExtra’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.153959+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     runExample
2022-12-06T14:26:10.154204+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.154230+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     runExample
2022-12-06T14:26:10.154470+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.154480+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     removeClass, show
2022-12-06T14:26:10.186342+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2022-12-06T14:26:10.186582+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.186599+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     filter, lag
2022-12-06T14:26:10.186863+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2022-12-06T14:26:10.186874+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2022-12-06T14:26:10.662438+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Rows: 351500 Columns: 4
2022-12-06T14:26:10.669632+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2022-12-06T14:26:10.669655+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Delimiter: ","
2022-12-06T14:26:10.669660+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: chr (3): Drug.name, Cell line, Cancer-Type
2022-12-06T14:26:10.669663+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: dbl (1): IC50
2022-12-06T14:26:10.684681+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
2022-12-06T14:26:10.684686+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
2022-12-06T14:26:10.932256+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Rows: 242399 Columns: 4
2022-12-06T14:26:10.947141+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2022-12-06T14:26:10.947164+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Delimiter: ","
2022-12-06T14:26:10.947170+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: chr (3): Drug.name, Cell line, Cancer-Type
2022-12-06T14:26:10.947174+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: dbl (1): IC50
2022-12-06T14:26:10.970421+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
2022-12-06T14:26:10.970429+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
2022-12-06T14:26:10.981035+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Error: 'www/Gene-expression-data-GDSC.csv ' does not exist in current working directory ('/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev').
2022-12-06T14:26:10.981050+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Shiny application exiting ...
2022-12-06T14:26:10.981096+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Execution halted
2022-12-06T14:42:07.810636+00:00 shinyapps[7827229]: Container event from container-7496175: stop
```

**EDIT**

@gokhancan told me the app might not be able to find the csv file so I got the working directory of server using `print(getwd())` according to his recommendation and then used `print(list.files(getwd(), recursive = T, full.names = T))`to print names of files inside that directory. Noticing logs, the working directory is `/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev` and the `Gene-expression-data-GDSC.csv` is present in the www directory of the server directory, but it gives an error: `'www/Gene-expression-data-GDSC.csv ' does not exist in current working directory ('/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev')`.

What is the problem?
These are the logs I get:

```
# some log outputs
#.....

# output of print(getwd())
2022-12-08T08:06:13.662714+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: [1] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev"

# outputs of print(list.files(getwd(), recursive = T, full.names = T))
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663864+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [1] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/app.R"                              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663874+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [2] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/LICENSE"                            
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663885+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [3] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/anytime"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663888+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [4] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/askpass"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663925+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [5] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/base64enc"             
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663936+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [6] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/BH"                    
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663949+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [7] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/bit"                   
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663952+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [8] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/bit64"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663955+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:   [9] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/bs4Dash"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663960+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [10] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/bslib"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663963+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [11] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/cachem"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663966+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [12] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/cli"                   
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663969+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [13] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/colorspace"            
2022-12-08T08:06:13.663987+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [14] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/colourpicker"          
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664015+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [15] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/commonmark"            
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664020+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [16] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/cpp11"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664023+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [17] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/crayon"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664028+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [18] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/crosstalk"             
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664048+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [19] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/curl"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664053+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [20] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/digest"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664061+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [21] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/dplyr"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664078+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [22] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/DT"                    
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664097+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [23] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/ellipsis"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664102+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [24] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/fansi"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664106+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [25] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/farver"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664109+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [26] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/fastmap"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664127+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [27] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/fontawesome"           
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664132+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [28] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/fresh"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664135+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [29] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/fs"                    
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664147+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [30] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/generics"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664164+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [31] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/ggExtra"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664169+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [32] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/ggplot2"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664188+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [33] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/ggrepel"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664195+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [34] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/glue"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664199+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [35] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/gtable"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664202+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [36] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/hms"                   
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664230+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [37] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/htmltools"             
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664235+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [38] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/htmlwidgets"           
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664241+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [39] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/httpuv"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664244+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [40] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/httr"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664274+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [41] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/isoband"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664280+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [42] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/jquerylib"             
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664286+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [43] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/jsonlite"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664289+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [44] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/labeling"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664309+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [45] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/later"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664314+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [46] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/lattice"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664317+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [47] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/lazyeval"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664336+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [48] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/lifecycle"             
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664341+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [49] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/magrittr"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664360+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [50] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/MASS"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664365+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [51] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/Matrix"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664368+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [52] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/memoise"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664371+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [53] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/mgcv"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664388+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [54] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/mime"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664396+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [55] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/miniUI"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664415+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [56] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/mnormt"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664420+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [57] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/munsell"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664428+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [58] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/nlme"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664431+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [59] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/openssl"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664445+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [60] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/pillar"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664463+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [61] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/pkgconfig"             
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664468+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [62] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/png"                   
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664482+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [63] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/prettyunits"           
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664488+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [64] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/progress"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664503+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [65] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/promises"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664522+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [66] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/psych"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664529+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [67] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/purrr"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664539+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [68] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/R6"                    
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664542+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [69] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/rappdirs"              
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664546+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [70] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/RColorBrewer"          
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664562+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [71] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/Rcpp"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664577+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [72] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/rlang"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664583+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [73] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/rstudioapi"            
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664586+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [74] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/sass"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664596+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [75] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/scales"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664599+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [76] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/shiny"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664606+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [77] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/shinydashboard"        
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664622+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [78] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/shinyjs"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664626+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [79] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/shinyWidgets"          
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664648+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [80] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/slickR"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664652+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [81] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/sourcetools"           
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664670+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [82] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/sys"                   
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664677+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [83] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/tibble"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664682+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [84] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/tidyr"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664686+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [85] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/tidyselect"            
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664703+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [86] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/tmvnsim"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664709+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [87] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/tzdb"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664719+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [88] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/utf8"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664737+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [89] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/vctrs"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664744+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [90] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/viridisLite"           
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664749+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [91] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/vroom"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664753+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [92] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/waiter"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664768+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [93] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/withr"                 
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664774+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [94] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/xml2"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664793+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [95] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/xtable"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664799+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [96] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/desc/yaml"                  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664814+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [97] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/packrat/packrat.lock"               
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664818+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [98] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/README.md"                          
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664841+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]:  [99] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/www/bb_plot.png"                    
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664882+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: [100] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/www/Drug-sensitivity-data-GDSC1.csv"
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664888+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: [101] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/www/Drug-sensitivity-data-GDSC2.csv"
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664900+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: [102] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/www/Gene-expression-data-GDSC.csv"  
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664918+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: [103] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/www/header_logo.png"                
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664923+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: [104] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/www/home_des.png"                   
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664936+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: [105] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/www/plots_combined.png"             
2022-12-08T08:06:13.664940+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: [106] "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev/www/scatter_plot.png"               
2022-12-08T08:06:14.127829+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: Rows: 351500 Columns: 4
# some logs outputs
#.......
# the error 
2022-12-08T08:06:14.371405+00:00 shinyapps[7840651]: Error: 'www/Gene-expression-data-GDSC.csv ' does not exist in current working directory ('/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev').

# some logs outputs
#.......
```

Comment: Can you try to print current directory on console using `print(getwd())` before reading the file ? And maybe you can try to print names of files inside that directory. I think the app can't find csv file.

Comment: @G.Can . I did that. The path is `C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev` and I got the list of files in that directory using`list.files(path = "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev")`.

Comment: the returned list of files are:`"app.R"  "cGEDs9.Rproj" "LICENSE" "README.md"    "rsconnect" "www"`.

Comment: @G.Can .  And then I used `list.files(path = "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/")` to see names of files inside www directory and this is the result:  `"bb_plot.png" "Drug-sensitivity-data-GDSC1.csv" "Drug-sensitivity-data-GDSC2.csv"
 "Gene-expression-data-GDSC.csv"   "header_logo.png"  "home_des.png" "plots_combined.png"   "scatter_plot.png"`

Comment: @G.Can . it seems all things are well.

Comment: In your local computer this directory is fine. But you're trying to deploy on a different server, you need to check the current directory **in the server**. From this code block, I can say current directory is `'/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev'`. So, that csv file not located inside this directory probably. You can print current directory when you deploy the app on shinyapps.io

Comment: @G.Can . Should I use `list.files(path = "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev")` in the console for that?

Comment: You can use that.
Here is an different approuch. When you deploy your R codes to shinyapps.io, before reading csv file:
First, find out what is your current directory using `print(getwd())`
Second, list the files inside that path. `list.files(getwd())`

Comment: @G.Can . Well I used `list.files(getwd())` before reading csv files and result is `"app.R"        "cGEDs9.Rproj" "LICENSE"      "README.md"    "rsconnect"    "www"`. But when I used `list.files(path = "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev")` it returns `character(0)`. What is the problem? Is it that app can not find the csv file?

Comment: can you try `list.files(getwd(), recursive = T, full.names = T)` instead of `list.files(getwd())` and write the output here please

Comment: @G.Can.  `[1] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/app.R"                                             
 [2] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/cGEDs9.Rproj"                                      
 [3] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/LICENSE"                                           
 [4] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/README.md"                                         
 [5] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/rsconnect/shinyapps.io/maryam-momeni/cGEDs-dev.dcf"
 [6] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/bb_plot.png"`

Comment: `[7] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/Drug-sensitivity-data-GDSC1.csv"               
 [8] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/Drug-sensitivity-data-GDSC2.csv"               
 [9] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/Gene-expression-data-GDSC.csv"                 
[10] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/header_logo.png"`

Comment: `[11] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/home_des.png"                                  
[12] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/plots_combined.png"                            
[13] "C:/Users/HAMRAH/Desktop/cGEDs-dev/www/scatter_plot.png"`

Comment: Directories starting with `C:/` point to directories on the local computer. You need to run this code on the server. Expected result: `/srv/connect/apps/.....`

Comment: please review docs https://docs.posit.co/shinyapps.io/Storage.html

Comment: @gokhancan .I read that document. But there is one thing that I don't understand: I use the console of the R file for running `list.files(path = "/srv/connect/apps/cGEDs-dev")`. Should I run it elsewhere so that I can get access to the server?

Comment: I added an answer, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This question is answered at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74727824/my-shiny-app-can-not-find-one-of-csv-files-when-deploying-on-shinyapps-io-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey after these tons of comments I've created a simple shiny app.

Here is my app directory:

```
└───sapp
    │   server.R
    │   ui.R
    │
    └───data
            testdata.csv
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    print(getwd())
    print(list.files(getwd()))
    t = read.csv('data/testdata.csv')
    
    # some code blocks........
    #......................


})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    # some code blocks........
    #......................
    
))
```

**And I deployed my app to shinyapps.io.**

Now first, you can find the output of `print(getwd())` or a similar output from the "Logs" tab of the application deployed on shinyapps.io.
My testdata.csv file located inside "data" folder. So you can see the output describing this folder later in this sentence.

Here is the log output from shinyapps.io:

```
# some log outputs............
# ........................
# ........................
2022-12-07T11:35:12.927630+00:00 shinyapps[7836727]: Shiny application starting ...
2022-12-07T11:35:12.954219+00:00 shinyapps[7836727]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:44639
2022-12-07T11:35:17.064371+00:00 shinyapps[7836727]: [1] "/srv/connect/apps/sapp"
2022-12-07T11:35:17.064406+00:00 shinyapps[7836727]: [1] "data"     "packrat"  "server.R" "ui.R"    
2022-12-07T11:35:17.065431+00:00 shinyapps[7836727]: Warning in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
2022-12-07T11:35:17.065464+00:00 shinyapps[7836727]:   incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'data/testdata.csv'
```

As you see, output of print() function is here. I think this answer might help you.

Comment: Thank you, @gokhancan. I did it, and I could obtain the results of print(getwd()) and print(list.files(getwd())). I updated my question with the new logos I got. Would you please see the edit?